# How to duplicate a window's clientarea to another window?

Tags: c++, python, c, winapi, api

I want to create a simple project (the language doesn't really matter/but I prefer C++) which simply takes a window title as it's input and duplicate it's visual part, bit by bit, to a new window. just like a mirror better I'd say.
As far as I remember there was a win32 API for this but I can't remember, so would you please tell me how can I achieve this?
And please tell me, will your answers work with DirectX/Open-GL applications as well or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can get DC of first window, and get DC of second window. And after this do BitBlt or StretchBlt. It has to work... But I don't know what about DirectX/Open-Gl... I think it has to work too. But anyway. It won't take much time to check it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the source code for a program that will mirror other apps, you can use `StretchBlt()` instead of `BitBlt()`, this will not copy Menubars or popups.
Some apps like chrome, calculator, and camera use child windows for the visual part, and `FindWindow()` only scans through top-level windows for the title, so you can use `FindWindowEx()` with it to make that work!

```
#include <windows.h>

HWND sourceWindow;

void Mirror(HWND hwndSource, HWND hwndDst)
{
    HDC source = GetDC(hwndSource);
    HDC dst = GetDC(hwndDst);
    
    RECT srcSiz;
    GetClientRect(hwndSource, &srcSiz);
    
    SetWindowPos(hwndDst, NULL, 0, 0, srcSiz.right, srcSiz.bottom, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOZORDER);
    
    BitBlt(dst, 0, 0, srcSiz.right, srcSiz.bottom, source, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    
    ReleaseDC(hwndSource, source);
    ReleaseDC(hwndDst, dst);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT Message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (Message)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
            SetTimer(hwnd, 1, 500, (TIMERPROC) NULL);//This will refresh after every 500 ms
            break;
        case WM_TIMER:
            Mirror(sourceWindow, hwnd);
            break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            KillTimer(hwnd, 1);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, Message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG msg;
    
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 0, 0)));
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = "MyWindow";
    wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);
    
    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Window Registration Failed!", "Error!", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }
    
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, "MyWindow", "MyTitle", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 500, 500,
                            NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
                            
    if (!hwnd)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Window Creation Failed!", "Error!", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }
    
    
    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);
    
    sourceWindow = FindWindowA(NULL, "<WindowTitle>");//or you can use class name
    
    while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    
    return msg.wParam;
}
```